# XML, XSL transform

Tags: jquery, html, xml, xslt, xml-parsing

In my code I am taking Start date(11/31/2015) from XML and break it down into separate Month and day. I got it very well. However, When I am trying to convert month number into month name. The code which I used is not working.Also I am trying to add AM/Pm on Start time.

```
XSL Content enter code here
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:ext="metadata">

 <xsl:template match="/">
 <html>
 <head>

 <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
 <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
    window.alert = function(){};
    var defaultCSS = document.getElementById('bootstrap-css');
    function changeCSS(css){
        if(css) $('head > link').filter(':first').replaceWith('<link rel="stylesheet" href="'+ css +'" type="text/css" />'); 
        else $('head > link').filter(':first').replaceWith(defaultCSS); 
    }
      $( document ).ready(function() {
      var iframe_height = parseInt($('html').height()); 
      window.parent.postMessage( iframe_height, 'http://bootsnipp.com');
    });
   </script>

  <style>
    @import url("http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?   family=Lato:100,300,400,700,900,400italic");
    @import url("//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.css");
    body {
        padding: 60px 0px;
        background-color: rgb(220, 220, 220);
       }

     .event-list {
        list-style: none;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
     }
      .event-list > li {
        background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgb(51, 51, 51);
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.7);
        padding: 0px;
        margin: 0px 0px 20px;
      }
    .event-list > li > time {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 100%;
        color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
        background-color: blue;
        padding: 5px;
        text-align: center;
        text-transform: uppercase;
    }
    .event-list > li:nth-child(even) > time {
        background-color: rgb(165, 82, 167);
   }
   .event-list > li > time > span {
    display: none;
    }
   .event-list > li > time > .day {
    display: block;
    font-size: 28pt;
    font-weight: 100;
    line-height: 1;
   }
   .event-list > li time > .month {
    display: block;
    font-size: 12pt;
    font-weight: 450;
    line-height: 1;
}

.event-list > li > .info {
    padding-top: 5px;
    text-align: center;
}
.event-list > li > .info > .title {
    font-size: 10pt;
    font-weight: 700;
    margin: 0px;
}
.event-list > li > .info > .desc {
    font-size: 10pt;
    font-weight: 300;
    margin: 0px;
}



@media (min-width: 350px) {
    .event-list > li {
        position: relative;
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        height: 63px;
        padding: 0px;
    }

    .event-list > li > time,
    .event-list > li > img {
        width: 60px;
        float: left;
    }


    .event-list > li > .info {
        position: relative;
        height: 60px;
        text-align: left;
        padding-right: 40px;
    }   

}



    </style>                    
  </head>
 <body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="[ col-xs-12 col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-8 ]">
        <xsl:for-each select="Items/Item">
    <ul class="event-list">
                <li>

                    <time >



                        <span class="day"><xsl:value-of select="substring-  before(substring-after(StartDate,'/'),'/')"/></span>
                        <!--<span class="month"><xsl:value-of select="substring-before(StartDate,'/')"/></span> -->

          <xsl:param name="pMonthNames"/>

  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$month = 1">Jan</xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="$month = 2">Feb</xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="$month = 3">Mar</xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="$month = 4">Apr</xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="$month = 5">May</xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="$month = 6">Jun</xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="$month = 7">Jul</xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="$month = 8">Aug</xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="$month = 9">Sep</xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="$month = 10">Oct</xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="$month = 11">Nov</xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="$month = 12">Dec</xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>error: <xsl:value-of select="$month"/></xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>



                      <xsl:variable name="vMonthNames" select="document('')/*/xsl:param[@name='pMonthNames']/*"/>
                   <span class="month">
                   <xsl:value-of select="$vMonthNames[number(substring-before(current()/StartDate,'/'))]/text()"/>
                  </span>



                    </time>

                    <div class="info">
                        <h2 class="title"><xsl:value-of select="ParentActivityName"/></h2>
                        <p class="desc"><xsl:value-of select="ActivityName"/>
                         <xsl:text> Start Time:</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="floor((StartMinute div 60)- (12 * ((StartMinute div 60) > 12)) + (12 * ((StartMinute div 60) = 0)))"/></p>


                    <!--    <p class="desc"><xsl:text> End Time:</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="floor((EndMinute div 60)- (12 * ((EndMinute div 60) > 12)) + (12 * ((EndMinute div 60) = 0)))"/></p> -->
                    </div>

                </li>

            </ul>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </div>

        </div>
    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
  </xsl:stylesheet>
```

XML Content
    enter code here

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Items>
<Item>
<ActivityName>Eastern New Mexico - SPEC</ActivityName>
<ParentActivityName>Fall 2015 Volleyball</ParentActivityName>
<Description></Description>
<StartDate>11/13/2015 12:00:00 AM</StartDate>
<EndDate>11/13/2015 12:00:00 AM</EndDate>
<StartMinute>1140</StartMinute>
<EndMinute>1200</EndMinute>
<ActivityTypeCode>2</ActivityTypeCode>
<CampusName></CampusName>
<BuildingCode></BuildingCode>
<RoomNumber></RoomNumber>
<RoomName></RoomName>
</Item>
</Items>
```

Comment: Where is the main HTML document with the script being loaded from, also from `https://astraweb.tamuk.edu/`? Otherwise the same origin policy will not allow the script to access any iframe content.

Comment: It is on the same link https://astraweb.tamuk.edu/events/index.html

Comment: Load the document with XMLHttpRequest and use XSLTProcessor to perform the XSLT transformation. Constructing some XML as a string and throwing it as HTML into an iframe will not apply any XSLT stylesheet.

Comment: I have XSL document but how I will load XML document through link. It mean I do not have XML doc. It is link which display XML format on ifram

Comment: You have the URL of that iframe so you can certainly load it using XMLHttpRequest. Of course the whole problem could better be solved on the server when generating the XML by directly applying the XSLT there or at least by directly putting the `<?xml-stylesheet?>` processing instruction into the XML when generating it and sending it to the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the month name, try:

```
<span class="month">
    <xsl:value-of select="$vMonthNames[number(substring-before(current()/StartDate,'/'))]/text()"/>
</span>
```

**Important**: you must move the `pMonthNames` parameter and make it a child of stylesheet.

For the start time, try:

```
<p class="desc">
    <xsl:value-of select="ActivityName"/>
    <xsl:text> Start Time: </xsl:text>

    <xsl:variable name="h" select="floor(StartMinute div 60)" />
    <xsl:variable name="m" select="StartMinute mod 60" />

    <xsl:value-of select="($h + 11) mod 12 + 1"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="format-number($m, ':00')"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="substring(' AM PM', 1 + 3*($h > 11), 3)"/>
 </p>
```

---

### Added:

> I unable to fix month name code.

See if this works for you:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:param name="pMonthNames">
    <name><short>JAN</short>January</name>
    <name><short>FEB</short>February</name>
    <name><short>MAR</short>March</name>
    <name><short>APR</short>April</name>
    <name><short>MAY</short>May</name>
    <name><short>JUN</short>June</name>
    <name><short>JUL</short>July</name>
    <name><short>AUG</short>August</name>
    <name><short>SEP</short>September</name>
    <name><short>OCT</short>October</name>
    <name><short>NOV</short>November</name>
    <name><short>DEC</short>December</name>
</xsl:param>

<xsl:variable name="vMonthNames" select="document('')/*/xsl:param[@name='pMonthNames']/*"/>

<xsl:template match="/Items">
    <html>
        <body>
            <ul class="event-list">
                <xsl:for-each select="Item">
                    <li>
                        <!-- ... -->
                        <span class="month">
                            <xsl:value-of select="$vMonthNames[number(substring-before(current()/StartDate,'/'))]/text()"/>
                        </span>                   
                        <!-- ... -->                        
                    </li>       
                </xsl:for-each>
            </ul>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I unable to fix month name code. You code for time is working well thanks

Comment: @Unknown Try the stylesheet I have added to my answer.